Displaying Only Newly Added Data from an Excel file into Email's Message Content Using SharePoint's "When an item or a file is modified" trigger
I'm looking into sending an email that contains ONLY the newly added data from the excel file. The data in the excel file in a form of a table is illustrated in the following below:



Key
Date
Level




033113
9-Jul-24
Red1


033112
8-Jul-24
Green3


033111
7-Jul-24
Amber2



So for example, the newly added data into the excel file are ['Key'] = 033113, ['Date'] = 9 July 2024 and ['Level'] = Red1 and the previous known data are ['Key'] = 033112, ['Date'] = 8 July 2024 and ['Level'] = Green3.
My intention is whenever there is a newly added data into the excel file, it would trigger the flow to run in Power Automate through using the SharePoint's "When an item or a file is modified". After that, if the latest newly added data with the ['Key'] column (denoted as 033113) is greater than the previous data (denoted as 033112), then it would proceed to send in the email with ONLY the newly added data of ['Key'], ['Date'] and ['Level'].
This is my flow in Power Automate so far:
"When an item or a file is modified"  ---------->  "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)"  -----------> "Email"
Between the "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)" and "Email" action, I'm not sure what are the types of actions I should include to have a flow that has the function mentioned above. Need some guidance on this, thanks!
